# Read all button's tags

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxUVg.png)
Hi,

I am trying to change the Button's ForeColor based on the TAG properties, but I get an error instead, can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code 
Thank you

Sub SetBTkey(ByVal BT As String)

```
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            If ctrl.Tag.ToString.Contains(BT) = True Then
                CType(ctrl, Button).ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
            Else
                CType(ctrl, Button).ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

SetBTkey("BTkey01")

Comment: Are you sure Tag has content - it appears not from the error. Plus you should have ctrl.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen

Comment: Not every Tag has a content, here is what I am trying to achieve, I have a group of buttons called BTKey01 thru BTKey27 and I want to select any button from that group and change the color to green and the rest of the button's change the color to white, any help will be appreciated
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution

[Control array in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497403/control-array-in-vb-net)

Dim buttons As Button() = { Button1, Button2, … }

For Each button As Button In Buttons
    button.tag = "foo"
next